# Entity Framework table per type inheritance with PK->FK, not PK->PK

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have to create an entity framework model for a badly designed database. The database uses table per type inheritance but it does so with using a PK->FK relationship, not a PK->PK relationship. E.g.

```
Person
   PersonID (PK)
   Name

Employee
   EmployeeID (PK)
   PersonID (FK)
   DateStarted

HourlyEmployee
   HourlyEmployeeID (PK)
   EmployeeID (FK)
   HourlyRate
```

Obviously this is just badly designed, but I can't change it. Table per type inheritance in the entity framework essentially wants EmployeeID not to exist and the PK for Employee to be PersonID. Is it possible to create a model for this database, or do I choose another tool? any recommendations?

Comment: Are those FKs created with unique constraints?

Comment: Yes, these FKs are guaranteed to be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not map this as TPT inheritance because your database is configured in the way that doesn't allow you cheating EF.

If `Employee.EmployeeID` is auto-generated in the database and `Employee.PersonID` is unique (uniqueness must be enforced in the database) you should be able  (not tested) to cheat EF by simply mapping:

```
public Employee : Person {
    public DateTime DateStarted { get; set; }
}
```

This class will tell EF that `Employee` inherits key from Person (`PersonID`) and you will hide the real key from EF - this should work if the real key is auto-generated.

The problem is your next level of inheritance which breaks this pattern. To make this work your `HourlyEmployee` will have to reference `PersonID` - not `EmployeeID`. EF now doesn't know about `EmployeeID` existence so it even cannot map relation with `HourlyEmployee`.

TPT inheritance in code first has one additional limitation - PK column must have the same name in all tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model from the database if it exists but it might not be what you expect. EF sometimes doesn't work that great with weird database structures.